# PHP Login form Password Usernames doesn't work with "fgets" reading from .txt file

Tags: php, passwords, fgets

Firstly, I'm really sorry if I ask a stupid question but I've done all the possible researches for two days and my code still doesn't seem to be working.

Basically, I try to retrieve data from an .txt file and check the password and the username and if they match then the person is logged in. For some reason the is statement that checks the password and username doesn't even work with the correct data.

Here is the online link: http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ztoth01/p1/php_fma/index.php 
(page 3 is not working yet)

That is the bit I'm struggling with:

```
 if($form_is_submitted === true){

   $handle = fopen('data/usernames.txt','r'); //open the file to read

  while(!feof($handle)){                       
    $line = fgets($handle);

    if(empty($line)){
        break;
    }                                     //ignore the last line

    $data = explode(',',$line);           // explode each line
    $userName = $data[2];                 // assign the the username
    $passWord = $data[3];                 // assign the the password


  //checking the username and the password if they match and exist in the .txt file   
    if( $userName === $_POST['username'] &&  $passWord === $_POST['password']){
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        echo '<p>Finally it\'s working!! :) </p>';
    }else{
        $errors_detected = true;
        echo '<p>still not working working</p>'.PHP_EOL;
    }   
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Once again, I'm really sorry if I ask a very silly question. Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You better protect that `.txt` file there. Plus, use a DB and `password_hash()`. You will get hacked.

Comment: I would use `file()` instead of `fopen()` so you probably need to `trim($data[3])`.

Comment: I know .txt is not safe at all. It's part of the requirements for my coursework, otherwise I wouldn't use it. But Thanks,
I tried the trim and it's working now!! but still don't get it why it was necessary? Thanks so much!!